# Groovy closure to implement matcher in Fest

Tags: swing, groovy, cucumber-jvm, fest

I am trying to create a closure matcher for Fest with Groovy (2.1.6) like this:

```
def matcherLabel = [ isMatching: { JLabel label -> /* do something */ } ] as GenericTypeMatcher<JLabel>
```

GenericTypeMatcher is an abstract class with one method only to implement (isMatching (T t))

but I get this error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Error casting map to org.fest.swing.core.GenericTypeMatcher, Reason: null
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.asType(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:7562)
```

Is it possible what I am trying to do?

Comment: I'd say its possible as I've just tried and it worked (creating my own GenericTypeMatcher class though). Are you sure the error is exactly on that line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is that the `GenericTypeMatcher` class doesn't have a default, zero-parameter constructor.  Cast the map to an interface like `ComponentMatcher` instead.  If you can't use an interface, another alternative is to subclass `GenericTypeMatcher` and provide a zero-parameter constructor.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, it has a constructor parameter. Googling around looks is not possible having coercion with constructor parameters in Groovy. So I will use normal classes.