# Error casting map to grails.gorm.CriteriaBuilder

Tags: grails, mocking

Could someone please tell me why I am not able to mock CriteriBuilder in my test. When criteriaBuilderMock.createMock() is executed I am getting Error casting map to grails.gorm.CriteriaBuilder, Reason: null

Is it possible to mock CriteriaBuilder? Am I getting this error because grails does not allow mocking objects without default constructor? Is there work around?

```
@TestFor(ProductService)
class ProductServiceSpec extends Specification {

    void "test exists"() {
        given:
        def criteriaBuilderMock = mockFor(CriteriaBuilder);
        criteriaBuilderMock.createMock(); //<-- error org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Error casting map to grails.gorm.CriteriaBuilder, Reason: null
    }
}
```

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Groovy closure to implement matcher in Fest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451531/groovy-closure-to-implement-matcher-in-fest)

Answer (score 2):

The mocked class has to have a no-args constructor.